# Android httppost with httpget

Tags: android, http-post, http-get

First of all. Sorry for my bad enghlish.

I want to write a program what can communicate with my website with post/get parameters but when i run the progress httppost with http://xyz.xyz/?server&user=this&pass=that
it's not work... how can i fix this problem if i can do that.

the sintax

GET

1. username
2. password

POST

1. message
2. captcha

I know exists two method for this but i don't know one progress for these two method with together.

(httppost / httpget methods; but together... i need it)

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fully understand your question, but if you want to login to a website (HTTP POST and all), the below link might help.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Also, note, the "stringdata" and "id" given in the example is the id of the input parameter in the html code.

```
        <input id="___THIS HERE___" value="..etc" >
```

According to your question, I'd say you do it like this:

```
...
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "this"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "that"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
...
```

Comment: My Question is done, but your answer is good, it's the best way to do that..
Thanks your help :)